# Display:table-cell.Растянута первая ячейка. В чём проблема?

Tags: html, css, table

Почему у таблицы растягивается первый столбец? Разве они все не должны растягиваться пропорционально?

```css
body {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  font-family: Blippo, fantasy;
  color: #DC143C;
}

article {
  border: 1px solid black;
  display: table;
  margin: 30px auto;
}

.table-row {
  display: table-row;
  list-style: none;
}

.table-row li {
  display: table-cell;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <article class="table">
    <h1>
My CSS Table!
</h1>
    <ul class="table-row">
      <li>Cell-1</li>
      <li>Cell-2</li>
      <li>Cell-3</li>
      <li>Cell-4</li>
    </ul>
    <ul class="table-row">
      <li>Cell-1</li>
      <li>Cell-2</li>
      <li>Cell-3</li>
      <li>Cell-4</li>
    </ul>
    <ul class="table-row">
      <li>Cell-1</li>
      <li>Cell-2</li>
      <li>Cell-3</li>
      <li>Cell-4</li>
    </ul>
  </article>
</body>
```

Comment: Тема закрыта .Я разобрался

Comment: Ну так напишите сюда ответ (форма в нижней части страницы). Самоответы являются нормой на StackOverflow. Тем более что сюда придёт ещё множество людей с подобной проблемой.

Answer (score 0):

Потому что `table-row` должен быть в контейнере с `display: table`։

```css
body {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  font-family: Blippo, fantasy;
  color: #DC143C;
}

article {
  border: 1px solid black;
  display: table;
  margin: 30px auto;
}
.table{
  display: table;
}
.table-row {
  display: table-row;
  list-style: none;
}

.table-row li {
  display: table-cell;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <article class="table">
    <h1>
My CSS Table!
</h1>
    <div class="table">
      <ul class="table-row">
        <li>Cell-1</li>
        <li>Cell-2</li>
        <li>Cell-3</li>
        <li>Cell-4</li>
      </ul>
      <ul class="table-row">
        <li>Cell-1</li>
        <li>Cell-2</li>
        <li>Cell-3</li>
        <li>Cell-4</li>
      </ul>
      <ul class="table-row">
        <li>Cell-1</li>
        <li>Cell-2</li>
        <li>Cell-3</li>
        <li>Cell-4</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </article>
</body>
```